# GCC Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to understand the structure of the Abstract Syntax Tree that GCC constructs when it parses a source file, but I find it confusing, and there isn't much information available about it. Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: a quick search gave me this http://saturnman.me/?p=52

Comment: This seems very much like a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

GCC tree representation is described in the [GCC Internals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint) document, specifically the section about [GENERIC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html#GENERIC).

Comment: Or see the section GIMPLE: "The C and C++ front ends currently convert directly from front end trees to GIMPLE, and hand that off to the back end rather than first converting to GENERIC"